# C: fscanf does not change filestream

Tags: c, io, stream, scanf

I am writing a small c-program for reading data out of a textfile.
I am using c but my knowledge is very basic.

```
#define MAXLINELEN 200
void skipLines(FILE *, int );
int readnextval(FILE* , double *);

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE* in_File=fopen("input.txt","r");

char buffer[MAXLINELEN];
    skipLines(in_File,HEADERLINES);
    fscanf(in_File," %[^0-9\n] ",buffer);
    printf("buffer =%s\n",buffer);
    fscanf(in_File," %[^0-9\n] ",buffer);
    printf("buffer =%s\n",buffer);
    fscanf(in_File," %[^0-9\n] ",buffer);
    printf("buffer =%s\n",buffer);
}
```

My textfile has 2 Headerlines and the following line is something like:
SOMETEXT value value value
Output in console is:

```
buffer =SOMETEXT
buffer =SOMETEXT
buffer =SOMETEXT
```

Why isn't the fscanf function moving the pointer after reading the buffer string.
I was predicting output like this:

```
buffer =SOMETEXT
buffer = 
buffer =
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `HEADERLINES` here?

Comment: HEADERLINES is a predefined constant literally 2 in this example (number of headerlines)

Comment: Read [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html). Use the return value. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). **Use your debugger.** (`gdb`)

Comment: return value is:1 (first call), else zero

Comment: Likely input has a digit in it someplace.  Show input.txt

Comment: What happens if you test `fscanf(in_File,"%[^0-9\n]",buffer);` instead of `fscanf(in_File," %[^0-9\n] ",buffer);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thanks for helpful comments.
Buffer value and stream position stay unchanged, when fscanf can't find a fitting string to store (return value==0) in this example.